# How are polynomials graphs approximated?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

Say I have the data:

$x=[ 1, 2, 3.3, 4, 5.5, 8, 9, 10.2, 11, 45 ]$

$y=[ 9,27,64,91,164,330,462,540,630,10218]$

The data is subjective though.

How would one approximate a valid polynomial for this data?

[image: Graph of polynomial.]

Where the original function for finding this "fake" data was:

$5x^2+2x+3$

And the polynomial from the approximation is:

$5.0080x^2 + 1.6369x+3.1341$

Obviously I tweaked the fake data a slight bit to make it closer to a real scenario.

My initial thought was to brute-forcing using computers, because of their to do countless calculations per second, but there must be a better way?

Comment: Typically $n$ data points can be exactly fitted by an $n-1$ degree polynomial (in one variable), but this likely produces an "over-fitted" model that does not correspond to a natural extrapolation of data, and typically has oscillating overshoots on interpolated regions.  So one strategy is to fit lower degree polynomials to the data, using best fit by least squares or maximum error criteria, looking for a good trade-off between accurate fit and small degrees.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more data points than the degree of the polynomial, you can do a least squares fit.  The fact that it is a polynomial is not important.  The important point is that the fitting function (your polynomial) depends linearly on the parameters (the coefficients).  $x^2$ is not linear, but no matter.  You could as well fit a Fourier series, where the basis functions are sines and cosines instead of monomials.  Any linear analysis text will explain the process, which can be done using the normal equations.  I like chapter 15 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).  Obsolete versions are free online